# Why ios objective-c delegate are always called from the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delphi, delegates

under ios, if i create an object with an objective-c delegate object from a background thread then the delegate function will always be called from the main thread...

exemple of delegate object :

```
  {~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
  IALKVODelegate = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{B0C6720A-79B7-4FD6-B9E3-77594E905B3C}']
    procedure observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString; ofObject: Pointer; change: NSDictionary; context: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;

  {~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
  TALKVODelegate = class(TOCLocal, IALKVODelegate)
  private
    [Weak] FVideoPlayerControl: TALIOSVideoPlayer;
  public
    constructor Create(const aVideoPlayerControl: TALIOSVideoPlayer);
    procedure observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: NSString; ofObject: Pointer; change: NSDictionary; context: Pointer); cdecl;
  end;
```

observeValueForKeyPath will be always called in the main-thread no matter if the owner object and the delegate object was created in a background thread.

is their any workaround or it's a normal behavior ?

Comment: sorry didn't see the duplicate ! thanks !

Comment: Yes, that's the second most annoying thing about `observeValueForKeyPath`. It gets invoked on the main queue(only to watch us burn) :)